# Storing tinymce in mysql then retrieving - getting a few garbage characters

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I'm using Tinymce attached to a texarea as a simple HTML editor.  I store the HTML in a MySQL mediumtext field.  A blank line is encoded as <p> </p> in Tinymce's HTML view, which is just fine, but after I store it in the database it looks like <p>Â </p>.  I am using MySQL PDO without using htmlentities or other processing of the string other than whatever PDO does.  The html5 character set is UTF-8.  The table collation is utf8_general_ci.

>> added note: I wrote out to a file what I was getting in $_POST and it definitely shows the garbage characters, x'C2A0', so it has to be some sort of Tinymce issue.  Does anyone have any ideas?

>> I just submitted this as a bug report on the Tinymce web site, as I haven't gotten answer here, nor on the Tinymce forum.